# Numerical differential equation solver algorithm segfaults unexpectedly

Tags: c, math, segmentation-fault, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I was trying to solve a differential equation in octave but it takes forever with the differential unit I have chosen, so I decided to code it in C. Here is the algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double J = 5.78e-5; // (N.m)/(rad/s^2)
double bo = 6.75e-4; // (N.m)/(rad/s)
double ko = 5.95e-4; // (N.m)/rad
double Ka = 1.45e-3; // (N.m)/A
double Kb = 1.69e-3; // V/(rad/s)
double L = 0.311e-3; // mH
double R = 150; // ohms
double E = 5; // V

// Simulacion
int tf = 2;
double h = 1e-6;

double dzdt, dwdt, didt;

void solver(double t, double z, double w, double i) {
    printf("%f %f %f\n", z, w, i);
    if (t >= tf) {
        printf("Finished!\n");
        return; // End simulation
    }
    else {
        dzdt = w;
        dwdt = 1/J*( Ka*i - ko*z - bo*w );
        didt = 1/L*( E - R*i - Kb*w );
        // Solve next step with newly calculated "initial conditions"
        solver(t+h, z+h*dzdt, w+h*dwdt, i+h*didt);
    }
}

int main() {
    solver(0, 0, 0, 0);
    // Solve data
    // Write data to file
    return 0;
}
```

The differential unit being defined as `h` (as you may see), has to be that small, otherwise the values will get out of hand and the solution will not be correct. Now, with numerically greater values of `h`,  the program goes from start to end with no errors (except for `nan` values), but with the `h` I have chosen I get a segmentation fault; what could be causing this?

### Alternate Octave solution

After a friend of mine told me he was able to solve the equation using a differential step of `1e-3` using MATLAB, I found out that MATLAB has a "stiff" version of its `ode23` module--"stiff" meaning special for solving those differential equations that require an extremely small step size. I later searched for "stiff" ODE solvers in Octave and found that `lsode` pertains in that category. On the first try, `lsode` solved the equation in microseconds (both faster than MATLAB and my C implementation), and with a perfect solution. Long live FOSS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're recursion isn't terminating fast enough, so you're blowing your stack.

To get around this, just make it a loop, it doesn't look like you're actually doing anything that needs recursion.

I think this does it:

```
void solver(double t, double z, double w, double i) {
    while (!(t >= tf)) {
        printf("%f %f %f\n", z, w, i);
        dzdt = w;
        dwdt = 1/J*( Ka*i - ko*z - bo*w );
        didt = 1/L*( E - R*i - Kb*w );
        // Solve next step with newly calculated "initial conditions"
        t = t+h;
        z = z+h*dzdt;
        w = w+h*dwdt;
        i = i+h*didt;
    } 
    printf("Finished!\n");
}
```

---

As a side note, your function is eligible for tail recursion optimizations, so if you compile it with some optimizations turned on (-O2 for example), any decent compiler will actually be smart enough to make that a tail recursive call, and your program will not segfault.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you got already plenty of answers on your actual problem. I just want to draw your attention to another lib. Use [boost.odeint](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/index.html), that's basically the state-of-the-art library if you need a fast and easy to use ode solver. Forget about GSL, Matlab, etc., Odeint outperforms all of them.

Your program would then look like this:

```
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

typedef boost::array<double,3> State;

const double J  = 5.78e-5; // (N.m)/(rad/s^2)
const double bo = 6.75e-4; // (N.m)/(rad/s)
const double ko = 5.95e-4; // (N.m)/rad
const double Ka = 1.45e-3; // (N.m)/A
const double Kb = 1.69e-3; // V/(rad/s)
const double L  = 0.311e-3; // mH
const double R  = 150; // ohms
const double E  = 5; // V

void my_ode( State const &s , State &dsdt , double t ) {
   double const &z = s[0],    // this is just a name
                &w = s[1],    // forwarding for better
                &i = s[2];    // readability of the ode
   dsdt[0] = w;
   dsdt[1] = 1./J * ( Ka*i - ko*z - bo*w );
   dsdt[2] = 1./L * ( E - R*i - Kb*w );
}

void printer( State const &s , double t ) {
   std::cout << s[0] << " " << s[1] << " " << s[2] << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   State s = {{ 0, 0, 0 }};
   integrate_const(
      euler<State>() , my_ode , s , 0. , 2. , 1e-6 , printer
   );
}
```

Comment: Hm perhaps I might try this one on a future event, but in fact I just decided to write this code in C because Octave was taking ages in calculating a numerical solution. The implementation I wrote with the solution suggested does a decent time :)

Answer (score 2):

The solver function calls itself recursively. How deep? Probably several million times. Are you running out of stack space? Each recursion needs space for four doubles and a stack frame, that quickly adds up.

I suggest you rewrite the solver as an iterative instead of recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

As @hexist says, you don't need recursion here.

Stack overflow:

```
==4734== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4734== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4734== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4734== Command: ./demo
==4734== 
==4734== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0x7fe801ff8
==4734== 
==4734== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4734==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x7FE801FF8
==4734==    at 0x40054E: solver (demo.c:18)
==4734==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==4734==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==4734==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==4734==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==4734==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==4734== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0x7fe801fe8
==4734== 
==4734== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4734==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x7FE801FE8
==4734==    at 0x4A226E0: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:58)
==4734==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==4734==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==4734==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==4734==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==4734==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==4734== 
==4734== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4734==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4734==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==4734== 
==4734== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4734== 
==4734== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4734== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing 1e6 recursive calls on solver. I guess you run out of stack. Try a loop inside solver with updating your variables instead of recalling the function.

pseudo code:

```
 while t < tf
      do dt step
      t = t + dt
```

and so on